# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got String

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I have a dropdown in vue js.

```
<v-flex> <v-select label="Select Province" v-bind:items="listProvince" outline v-model="province" persistent-hint @change="loadCity()"></v-select> 
</v-flex>
```

and in the 'listProvince' I am getting data and displayed in the dropdown but in console I am getting this error `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got String.`

This is the vue js code:

```
    export default {
  props: ["updateView","newBooking"],

  data() {
    return {
      selected: [0],
      shipper: "",
      address: "",
      barangay: "",
      city: "",
      province: "",
      phone: "",
      listProvince:"",
      selectedCity:"",
      bookingObject: {},
      isNewBk: false,
    };
  }
}
```

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: I mean, the error is pretty sefl-explanatory. You're tring to bind a string (province) to something that expects an array (v-bind:items).

Comment: where do i declare items as array here?

Comment: You didn't, which is the problem.

Comment: i am new to vue js so where do i declare it? thanks

Comment: `province: "",` It should be `province: ["something", "something"],`

Comment: is it in the data section?

Comment: Probably, I have never used Vue. Whereever you declare the property province, which is bound to `<select v-bind:items` , you should declare it as `[]`

Comment: i want string in province and i am declared it as string in the data section but still getting error

Comment: You SHOULDN'T declare it as a string. `selectedProvince` should be a string, `province` should be renamed to `provinces` and it should be an array: `["province1", "province2"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

Here i declared `province` as string and `listProvince` as array

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer with an example...
example from Vue site:

```
  props: {
  title: String,
  likes: Number,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  commentIds: Array,
  author: Object,
  callback: Function,
  contactsPromise: Promise // or any other constructor
}
```

for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone still feel confuse on ramees answer like I did, here is the real example of the final setting

```
data() {
  return {
    province: "",
    listProvince:['option 1','option 2'],
  };
```

This declare listProvince as array (the dropdown select options) while province as string (the selected dropdown value).

Hope this provide additional help to someone who needs it!